# Github Actions, self-hosted runner: Possible to add options to 'docker create'?

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-actions-runners

**Summary:**

GitHub Actions on self-hosted runners are executed in docker containers that are started with a bunch of options, pre-determined by the actions/runner software. How can I elegantly add custom options for `docker create` and `docker run`?

**Details & Explanation**

When I run a github actions workflow on a self-hosted runner, the process starts as follows:

- Set up job
- Initialize containers

  - Checking docker version
  - Clean up resources from previous jobs
  - Create local container network
  - Starting job container *and HERE it becomes interesting*

The job container is started with a command like this, as I can see in the log:

`/usr/bin/docker create --name da928aa7e61a4a44bd8e525...ea --label d36a64 --workdir /__w/xyz/xyz --network github_network_187...1631  -e "HOME=/github/home" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" etc. pp.`

Now, I have some very special tests to run as part of my CI build in that container. And for that, I would need to specify additional options for `/usr/bin/docker create` so imagine me needing any option from this [list](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/). Let's say `--cap-add`.

How can I do this? Some options came to my mind already:

- I can hack the runners, but they are auto-updating and I do not want to repeatedly do that.
- I can also move /usr/bin/docker to a different location and replace with a smart bash script, modifying the options and then calling docker. But that would mess with docker for all users on that system.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here:

The options can be specified as part of the workflow yml, as described here:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer

Example part of .github/workflows/workflow.yml

```
(...)
    container:
      image: contoso.azurecr.io/bionic-custom:latest
      options: --cap-add=NET_ADMIN
(...)
```